# Sending http requests from VPS to localhost server

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi3, vpn, vps, node-red

I have a Raspberry pi 3 running a local Node-Red server which communicates with an ESP8266 via MQTT protocol. I have an UI mounted on the Raspberry that allows me to to turn a light on and off through the ESP8266.

Then I configured a reverse proxy with nginx so I can host the UI with the Raspberry, allowing any device connected to the local network to use it.

Now I want to access it remotely, but I dont want to do port forwarding or touching the router configuration. Is there any way to access my local server from a VPS?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

Make VPN between your VPS and Raspberry Pi.

Make SSH tunnel between VPS and Raspberry Pi.

Use Dynamic DNS service like: NO-IP.com, DYN.com

Comment: Using Dynamic DNS service like no-ip, involves touching the router configuration, so it isn't a possible option